# how to extract array stdClass Object

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using a `CodeIgniter`.
i am getting value in array in controller but not getting in view. 
I am using this controller to get countries from database and on view page i want to show these countries in pagination.

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function admin($Username = NULL, $arr = NULL){

            if($this->session->userdata('is_log_in')){
                    $this->load->model('User');
                    $Username = $this->session->userdata('Username');
                    $form_data['results'] = $this->User->view_table($Username);
                    $arr = array();
                    $arr[]= $this->countries();
                    $arr[] = $form_data;
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($arr);  // getting all value here
                    $this->load->view('templates/header');
                    $this->load->view('User/User_admin', $arr);                  
                    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
               }else{
                    $form_data['msg'] = "Your Can't access this account";
                    $this->index($form_data);         
            }           
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
if(isset($arr)){
 if ($arr->num_rows() > 0){
          print_r($arr); 
}};
```

**updated**

Above problem is solved.

now updated question is how to extract these array stdClass Object

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ccode] => AF
                    [country] => Afghanistan
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ccode] => AX
                    [country] => Ã…land Islands
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ccode] => AL
                    [country] => Albania
                )
       )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [results] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [Username] => sachin
                            [First_name] => shagun
                            [Last_name] => sood
                            [Email] => sachin87@gmail.com
                            [Password] => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
                            [Conf_password] => 123
                            [Status] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Change `$arr[]` to `$arr['arr'][]` then `print_r($arr)` in your view to see its format

Comment: Are you print array in User/User_admin view ? Also check without any if statement in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->load->view('User/User_admin', $arr);
```

to

```
$data['arr'] = $arr;
$this->load->view('User/User_admin', $data);
```

Then $arr will work in the View file.

**For your second (updated) question:**

```
foreach ($arr[0] as $a)
{
    echo $a->ccode;
    echo $a->country;
}
```

And

```
echo $arr[1]['results'][0]->id;
echo $arr[1]['results'][0]->Username;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract for instance Afghanistan from your database object:

```
echo $arr[0][0]->country;
```